# How to detect type of stdout/stdin

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

I am not sure if it is valid question. Is it possible to detect type of stdout or stdin of python script? I wanted to check if stdin/ stdout is a folder/ derectory or data or binary types.

Basically I am trying to extract files from archive using python script. However, instead of extracting, the script I use write in to stdout. I just want to manipulate this stdout to find directory then create in the destination then find data/file/bin and extract from archive to destination directory.

Is it possible to do that?

**Updtate**

Here is what the scripts lists from iso container where `/BOOT/GRUB2_EF` is a directory.

```
C:\Users\Sundar\Documents\multibootusb>iso9660.py i:\home\sundar\openSUSE-13.1-K
DE-Live-x86_64.iso
/
/BOOT
/BOOT/0XA89369.
/BOOT/BOOTPART.CFG
/BOOT/GRUB2_EF
/BOOT/GRUB2_EF/GRUB.CFG
```

I tryid to create directory using this command:-

```
C:\Users\Sundar\Documents\multibootusb>iso9660.py i:\home\sundar\openSUSE-13.1-K
DE-Live-x86_64.iso /BOOT/GRUB2_EF/THEMES > dir
```

However, this is what i got and it is not a directory...

```
C:\Users\Sundar\Documents\multibootusb>dir
.
.
23/02/2014  11:52 AM             5,000 detect_iso.py
23/02/2014  11:53 AM             3,152 detect_iso.pyc
23/02/2014  06:07 PM             2,048 dir
16/02/2014  07:30 PM    <DIR>          dist
08/12/2013  06:31 AM               230 install_distro.py
```

**Update2**

```
C:\Users\Sundar\Documents\multibootusb>iso9660.py i:\home\sundar\openSUSE-13.1-K
    DE-Live-x86_64.iso /ISOLINUX.CFG > file.cfg
```

Here is the content of file.cfg

```
default openSUSE_13.1_KDE_Live
implicit 1
display isolinux.msg
.
.
```

Comment: `stdin`/`stdout` can never be a directory. It can be a file or a file-like object (stream).

Comment: I also thought like that. But the iso-extract script mentioned in the question writes everything in to stdout.

Comment: Can't you just use output redirection? `program_name arg1 arg2 > where_you_want_the_output_to_go.whatever` from the shell and you're done.

Comment: It is module to list and extract files from iso container. It actually extract it to stdout. But I want to exxtract files out of container instead of just writing it to stdout...

Comment: The way you're running it, it doesn't seem to be extracting the files. It's just listing their names. If you wrote the program, you'll want to write something that actually extracts files. If you didn't write the program, you may be able to find the solution you're looking for in the program's documentation.

Comment: The script is not written by me. I said it is extracting it to stdout. Updated the original post to show the extraction of file...

Comment: It is *not* extracting anything, as @user2357112 correctly noted.

Comment: No. It is. `/ISOLINUX.CFG` is a file residing in the iso container. See my update2.

Comment: Depending on what `ISOLINUX.CFG` is supposed to contain, it looks like your latest attempt in update 2 may have worked. What's wrong with it?

Comment: That is what I am exactly talking about here. How do I identify /something is a directory and /something1 is a file? both are writen in to stdout.

Comment: What I am trying to do is that extract files out of iso container with keeping the path intact based on list generated by the script.

Comment: You can't have stdout be a directory. If this program is supposed to be able to extract directories, there's no way it can do that through stdout. The solution is probably in the documentation.

Comment: I came here because there is no documentation exist and author has not responded to the issue I have opened/emailed:-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is the tool you are using?

https://github.com/barneygale/iso9660/blob/master/iso9660.py

This tool does one of two things:

1. Print a list of files in the ISO.
2. Extract *one* file from the ISO.

That's it. If you want it to extract all files that you are seeing, you will need to invoke it once for every file. I don't know much about cmd.exe scripting, but you might be able to take the output of iso9660.py where it prints every file and pipe it into a for loop that runs iso9660.py again once for every file.

Per a note from the OP, the only way to skip directories in the output is to skip lines that don't have a "." in them.

Comment: yes. You are correct and that is what exactly I have done. Finally i found the solution by going through the list generated by the script. The trick was that "." character was available if the path is leading to a file (even file having without extension). You may include this in your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Sure, I'll add a comment – but I don't understand what you are saying. "." character was available?

Comment: Look at my first update where `/BOOT` and `/BOOT/GRUB2_EF` are directory and rest all files. This is the same case with all the ISOs I have tested. And I don't find any other clue to solve the issue.